# How to get a single column's values into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I'm doing something like this to select a single column of data:

```
points = Post.find_by_sql("select point from posts")
```

Then passing them to a method, I'd like my method to remain agnostic, and now have to call hash.point from within my method. How can I quickly convert this into an array and pass the data set to my method, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

In Rails 3.2 there is a [pluck method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) for this

Just like this:

```
Person.pluck(:id) # SELECT people.id FROM people
Person.pluck(:role).uniq # unique roles from array of people
Person.distinct.pluck(:role) # SELECT DISTINCT role FROM people SQL
Person.where(:confirmed => true).limit(5).pluck(:id)
```

[Difference between uniq and distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575398/rails-uniq-vs-distinct)

Comment: How can an array inherit a query result's ordering with pluck?

Comment: Post.order(:score).pluck(:score) is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: To pluck ids there is a special method: `Person.ids`.

Comment: Also look into Ernie Miller's gem Valium https://github.com/ernie/valium especially if you're on an older Rails or want multiple columns

Comment: As of Rails 5.0, it is now recommended to use `distinct` instead of `uniq`: so `Person.distinct.pluck(:role)`

Answer (score 17):

You should use the `pluck` method as @alony suggested. If you are stuck before Rails 3.2 you can use the ActiveRecord `select` method together with `Array#map`:

```
Post.select(:point).map(&:point)
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

before Ruby 1.9 you'd have to do `.map{|x| x.title}` though, because `Symbol#to_proc` (aliased by the unary `&` operator) is not defined in earlier versions of Ruby.

Comment: Thanks. I saw you commented on the new Pluck method. Can you do the same with that?

Comment: Yes, if you read @alony's answer carefully, you will notice that she already included an example that does this.

Answer (score 5):

If you see the definition of select_values , then it using 'map(&:field_name)'

```
  def select_values(arel, name = nil)
    result = select_rows(to_sql(arel), name)
    result.map { |v| v[0] }
  end
```

The common and general Rails way to collect all the fields values in array is like :

```
points = Post.all(:select => 'point').map(&:point)
```

Comment: Good point. Thank you. This works great, and lets me still apply order and other things to the query, unlike the Post.select example.

Comment: I dont agree with you, @franklinstine: `Post.select(:point).limit(1)` performs `SELECT point FROM "posts" LIMIT 1` whereas `Post.all(:select => :point).limit(1)` raises a `NoMethodError`. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I agree with your comments. But I am not getting where mention in the post to use :
Post.all(:select => :point).limit(1)
Ofcourse it will give error "undefined method `limit'"

Comment: @franklinstine said he prefers your method because he could chain other statements after it, i just wanted to make clear that this is not true

Comment: Yes @padde you mis-inferred. I was saying you can still apply order and other query statements such as: Post.all(:select => 'score', :order => 'score ASC').map(&:score).

Comment: Ok, now i see. I have to admit though, that using the `pluck` method as @alony suggested is the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
points = Post.all.collect {|p| p.point}
```

Comment: This works, but you select all fields from the database and then filter the result in Ruby whereas the `select` statement only fetches the specified columns.