# ruby - array of arrays - how to select unique elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays, unique, subset

I have a "Q&A" array and each element is a subarray of three elements (Q, A and Animal).
How can I select all the unique animals?

I can select the animals alone with:

```
[@q_and_a[0][2]] + [@q_and_a[1][2]] + [@q_and_a[2][2]] +[@q_and_a[3][2]] 
# => ["Elephant", "Elephant", "Spider", "Spider"]
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: If you are using rails (activerecord) you have the `#pluck` method: `animals = QnAModel.pluck(:animal).uniq`. I know it's not what you are looking for, but many might be. Se also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9872725/741850

Answer (score 5):

Use the [**`map`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and **[`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)** function

```
@q_and_a.map { |a| a[2] }.uniq
```

Answer (score -1):

if your variable is called myElems then you can use the following:

```
myElems = [@q_and_a[0][2]] + [@q_and_a[1][2]] + [@q_and_a[2][2]] +[@q_and_a[3][2]]
myElems.uniq
# => ["Elephant","Spider"]
```

Here is a [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with the info on it

Answer (score -2):

```
@q_and_a.map{|a| a[2]}.group_by{|e| e}.select{|_, v| v.length == 1}.keys
```

Comment: I guess that depends on how you read the question, I see both as valid possibilities.  Given the OP's example output ( No "unique" animals ) I lean towards my interpretation.

Comment: @jondavidjohn You are right. what it says as the question does not match with the examples. I took what the question says, and you took what the example suggests.

Comment: @jondavidjohn You mention the OPs example output, but notice that that is not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: right, he's just showing us his data set... no unique animals.