# how to select all values from column a take them to new array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

i have a model `Timer(id:integer, track:string, time_point:integer)`
before this question i asked on stackoverflow about reorganizing my array with integer values to array with ranges and took a pretty nice answer(biggest thanks for steenslag):

```
array = [1,4,10,14,22]
array.unshift(-1)
ranges = array.each_cons(2).map{|a,b| a+1..b} #=>[0..1, 2..4, 5..10, 11..14, 15..22]

array.shift
```

now i want to apply this solution and create an integer array with all my time_points for next reorganizing. how could i get this array?

thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a single column's values into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869870/how-to-get-a-single-columns-values-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method to get all the column values as an `Array`.

```
time_points = Time.pluck(:time_point)
```