# Rails: uniq vs. distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can someone briefly explain to me the difference in use between the methods `uniq` and `distinct`?

I've seen both used in similar context, but the difference isnt quite clear to me.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**Rails queries acts like arrays**, thus `.uniq` produces the same result as `.distinct`, but

- `.distinct` is sql query method
- `.uniq` is array method

**Note**: In Rails 5+ `Relation#uniq` is deprecated and recommended to use `Relation#distinct` instead.
See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

**Hint**:

Using `.includes` before calling `.uniq/.distinct` can *slow* or *speed up* your app, because

- `uniq` won't spawn additional sql query
- `distinct` will do

But both results will be the same

Example:

```
users = User.includes(:posts)
puts users
# First sql query for includes

users.uniq
# No sql query! (here you speed up you app)
users.distinct
# Second distinct sql query! (here you slow down your app)
```

This can be useful to make performant application

**Hint**:

Same works for

- `.size` vs `.count`;
- `present?` vs `.exists?`
- `map` vs `pluck`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have a question: Doesn't it depend on the number of rows returned by the db?  If you have a massive number of results vs a small number of rows, then the db might perform better than ruby?

Comment: @GLaDOS yes, *rails app is like a building*: on the first floor we have sql, on the second and others we have business logic, on the last floor we have a view for users. 1) In case if user doesn't need any data, we should not lift the data from the first floor to last. So it means we shouldn't fetch the data on sql layer, not to lift it on rails one (so use `.limit(25)` method instead of `.first(25)`). 2) Also in case we have have missed any data of first floor. It not efficient to running back on the first floor to grab additional data from sql. So in that case use `.includes(:comments)`. Etc

Answer (score 7):

Rails 5.1 has removed the uniq method from Activerecord Relation and added distinct method...

- If you use uniq with query it will just convert the Activerecord Relaction to Array class...
- You can not have Query chain if you added uniq there....(i.e you can not do User.active.uniq.subscribed it will throw error `undefined method subscribed for Array` )
- If your DB is large and you want to fetch only required distinct entries its good to use distinct method with Activerecord Relation query...

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Documentation, please?

Comment: if you want to see PR or discussion in rails about it https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20198

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq):

> `uniq(value = true)`
>
> **Alias** for [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#distinct`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct)

Comment: apidock.com isn't Rails documentation, and it's no longer maintained. A better source is https://api.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 3):

Its not exactly answer your question, but what I know is:

If we consider ActiveRecord context then **uniq** is just an alias for **distinct**. And both work as removing duplicates on query result set(which you can say up to one level).

And at **array** context uniq is so powerful that it removes duplicates even if the elements are nested. for example

```
arr = [["first"], ["second"], ["first"]]
```

and if we do

```
arr.uniq
```

answer will be : `[["first"], ["second"]]`

So even if elements are blocks it will go in deep and removes duplicates.

Hope it helps you in some ways.