# Unknown column error in has_many through association after upgrade to rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've recently upgraded an application to from rails 4 to 5. I've started receiving an Unknown Column error on an association which was previously working.

I have three classes set out like this:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :department_users
  has_many :departments through: :department_users
  has_many :writable_staffs,  -> {where('department_users.write = 1').uniq}, through: :departments, source: :staffs
end
```

```rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :department_users
  has_many :users, through: :department_users
end
```

```rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :department_users
  has_many :users, through: :department_users
end
```

```rb
class DepartmentUse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :department
end
```

In my department_users table I have a boolean column 'write'.

If I run User.first.writable_staffs I recieve the following error:

```rb
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'department_users.write' in 'where clause': SELECT `staffs`.* FROM `staffs` WHERE (department_users.write = 1)
```

I'm able to fix it by replacing the writable_staffs association in user.rb with

```rb
  has_many :writable_departments, -> {where('department_users.write = 1')}, through: :department_users, source: :departments
  has_many :writable_staffs, through: :writable_departments, source: :staffs
```

Which is fine, but I don't understand why the previous code stopped working? Can anyone shine some light on it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575398/rails-uniq-vs-distinct first answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was with using "uniq" which was depreciated with rails 5. After replacing it with distinct, the original code ran as before.