# Rails 5 hasMany through is not filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I am migrating from Rails 4 to Rails 5 and got into this problem. I have the `hasMany` `through` relationship to connect the `Track` and the `RightHolder` classes:

```rb
class RightHolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :right_holder_tracks, class_name: 'TrackRightHolder', dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :tracks, -> { uniq }, through: :right_holder_tracks
end

class TrackRightHolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :right_holder
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :track_right_holders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :right_holders, -> { uniq }, through: :track_right_holders
end
```

In Rails 4 this was working perfectly, but in Rails 5, when I try to get:

```rb
Track.first.right_holders
RightHolder.first.tracks
```

The Rails application does these queries:

```
select * from right_holders
select * from tracks
```

What am  I doing wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 5, relation `uniq` was deprecated in favor of `distinct` :
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575398/rails-uniq-vs-distinct/39578193#39578193)

Answer (score 1):

just change `{ uniq }` to `{ distinct }`