# ActiveRecord - query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I am trying to generate such SQL query using Active Record:

```
SELECT  provinces.name, provinces.code FROM "provinces" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."province_id" = "provinces"."id" WHERE (customers.name LIKE "Kirk%")
```

I have this code:

```
Province.select('provinces.name, provinces.code')
        .joins(:customers)
        .find_by('customers.name LIKE "Kirk%"')
```

which works fine, however I think that a concern here is the "double" quote. This might be a problem especialy where I'd like to put in there params hash value, it will not allow to use interpolation:

```
"#{Kirk}%"
```

The query would then look like this:

```
SELECT  provinces.name, provinces.code FROM "provinces" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."province_id" = "provinces"."id" WHERE (customers.name LIKE "#{Kirk}%")
```

Is there a better way to write this part without using "double" quotes?

```
('customers.name LIKE "Kirk%"')
```

I've already tried this:

```
customers = Customer.where('name LIKE ?', 'Kirk%')
Province.select('provinces.name, provinces.code')
        .joins(:customers)
        .where('customers.name' => customers )
```

This code generates an SQL query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT provinces.name, provinces.code, customers.name FROM "provinces" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."province_id" = "provinces"."id" WHERE "customers"."name" IN ('580', '882', '1149', '1299', '2864', '2959', '3855', '4405', '5384', '6481', '10937')
```

However this query is not good for me, because it returns IDs instead of names and therefore it does not return any customers and of course does not find any matching provinces names.

How do I write this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a single column's values into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869870/how-to-get-a-single-columns-values-into-an-array)

Comment: replace your `.find_by('customers.name LIKE "Kirk%"')` with `where('customers.name LIKE ?', "#{your_variable}%"` and everything will be escaped for you, no need to worry about the double quotes.

Comment: Awesome! This solves my problem! Thank you so much :)))